# How to send image from suitecrm to Api

Tags: php, facebook, sugarcrm, facebook-marketing-api, suitecrm

I have a file type field which select the file from user PC it can be a video/image.
I have some logic in before save hooks logic which send the selected file to a server..

I need the uploaded file url which my api needs to send.
e.g $bean->file->url

or is there any other way?

Api call:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdImage;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdImageFields;

$image = new AdImage(null, 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = '<IMAGE_PATH>';

$image->create();
echo 'Image Hash: '.$image->{AdImageFields::HASH}.PHP_EOL;
```

please guide

Api reference: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image

Comment: Usually uploads on the CRM are located on upload folder, but its access is restricted by .htaccess. The bean ID is usually used to name the file on disk.
With the image ID you can form the download link. 
you might  require to authenticate before accessing the file